# How to extract date and time from standard datetime format?

Tags: swift

I am getting a string from API containing date and time as:

```
 createdAt = "2019-08-12T10:34:05.000Z"
```

I need to extract date from this string and time also.
And how can I get difference as time between two given date strings?

e.g. If I have two strings as:

```
StartedOn = "2019-08-12T10:32:18.000Z"
StopedOn = "2019-08-12T10:34:05.000Z".
```

How to get time from start to stop.

swift 4, Xcode 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **`DateFormatter`** to get the `Date` instance from the `String`, i.e.

```
let str = "2019-08-12T10:34:05.000Z"
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
let date = formatter.date(from: str)
```

Now, to get the time difference  use `timeIntervalSince(_:)` with the 2 `Date` objects, i.e.

```
let startedOn = "2019-08-12T10:32:18.000Z"
let stoppedOn = "2019-08-12T10:34:05.000Z"
if let startedOnDate = formatter.date(from: startedOn), let stoppedOnDate = formatter.date(from: stoppedOn) {
    let timeInterval = stoppedOnDate.timeIntervalSince(startedOnDate)
    print(timeInterval)
}
```

In case you need more detailed components between 2 `Date` objects, use `Calendar` object like so,

```
if let startedOnDate = formatter.date(from: startedOn), let stoppedOnDate = formatter.date(from: stoppedOn) {
    let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    let components = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second], from: startedOnDate, to: stoppedOnDate)
    print(components) //hour: 0 minute: 1 second: 47
}
```

**Edit:**

To get the `date` and `time` separately from `Date` object,

```
let str = "2019-08-12T10:34:05.000Z"
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
if let date = formatter.date(from: str) {
    formatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm:ss a"
    let timeStr = formatter.string(from: date)
    print(timeStr) //add timeStr to your timeLabel here...

    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    let dateStr = formatter.string(from: date)
    print(dateStr) //add dateStr to your dateLabel here...
}
```

Comment: its really helpful, can I get the am/pm as: 10:30 am ??

Comment: yes it is resolved, but I am wandering how to get time and date from 'optional()' and assign them to labels.

Comment: @user11596918 Edited the answer. Check that out.

Comment: I totally forgot this thing. Silly mistake!! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this :D

```
import datetime

StartedOn = "2019-08-12T10:32:18.000Z"
StopedOn = "2019-08-12T10:34:05.000Z"     
StartedOn = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(StartedOn[:-1]) 
StoppedOn = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(StopedOn[:-1]) 

print(StoppedOn - StartedOn)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two dedicated date formatters for that purpose, [`ISO8601DateFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/iso8601dateformatter) to convert the ISO8601 string to `Date`

```
let isoFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
isoFormatter.formatOptions = [.withInternetDateTime, .withFractionalSeconds]

let createdAtDate = isoFormatter.date(from: "2019-08-12T10:34:05.000Z")

let startedOn = "2019-08-12T10:32:18.000Z"
let stopedOn = "2019-08-12T10:34:05.000Z"
let startedOnDate = isoFormatter.date(from: startedOn)!
let stopedOnDate = isoFormatter.date(from: stopedOn)!
```

and [`DateComponentsFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/datecomponentsformatter) to get a `m:ss` string from the difference between start and end date

```
let componentsFormatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
componentsFormatter.allowedUnits = [.minute, .second]
let duration = componentsFormatter.string(from: startedOnDate, to: stopedOnDate)
```